# Need to get an equivalent item in list box when I input a number

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm new to c# and I've been struggling what to do with my program. Im doing an Alias Generator program. When I input a number in a `textbox` (ex. 1-12) I should get the equivalent Item in the `ListBox`.

```
lblAlias.Content = lstBox1.Items(Convert.ToInt16)(txtMOB.Text)[0 - 1].ToString();
```

Comment: you need to get the item value from the listbox or what??

Comment: Please give example input and output, **and** explain how they are related.  Also give examples of what is in the ListBox.  Your question as written makes little sense...

Comment: Okay so when I input a number in textbox1 it only should be 1-12 coz it represents the month while in textbox2 i should only input 1-31 because it represents the days. I have two listbox. The first listbox is has 12 items for Textbox1 the second listbox has 31 items for textbox2. The final output should be the combine item in listbox1 and listbox2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely **NOT** a WPF programmer (I use WinForms, sorry), but it would look something like...

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int month, day;
        if (int.TryParse(txtMOB.Text, out month) && int.TryParse(txtDOB.Text, out day))
        {
            if(month >= 1 && month <= 12 && day >= 1 && day <=31)
            {
                lblAlias.Content = ((ListBoxItem)lstBox1.Items[month - 1]).Content.ToString()
                    + " " + ((ListBoxItem)lstBox2.Items[day - 1]).Content.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Month must be between 1 and 12, and Day must be between 1 and 31!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Month and/or Day!");
        }
    }
```